# Google oauth fail with "Code was already redeemed" error

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, django-allauth

I am trying to make authorization from Google on my website.

And at the step of exchanging `code` to `access_token` I obtain error:

```
Code was already redeemed
```

It happens with using `django-allauth` lib aswell as with using recommended by Google libs and code:

```
redirect_uri = 'http://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/'    
config = {u'web': {u'redirect_uris': redirect_uris,
                       u'token_uri': u'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                       u'auth_uri': u'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
                       u'client_id': client_id,
                       u'client_secret': client_secret,
                      }
              }
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(
        config,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
    )
    flow.redirect_uri = redirect_uri
    flow.fetch_token(code=code)
```

When I am using test config with localhost url on my local machine, authorization works fine.

But when I use production server i got error.

In google web application I have both redirect URIs:

```
http://localhost:8888/accounts/google/login/callback/
http://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

As I can see, `code` exahnging only once, so why it could happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like an expired short-lived code that needs to be refreshed. [Possible help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705682/google-api-php-offline-access-invalid-grant-code-was-already-redeemed). Are you using a refresh token?

Comment: Actually, I can't obtain refresh token, becouse `fetch_token` (where both token should come) fails. About short-live `code`: haven't found any info about that in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) app

Answer (score 1):

May be late answer, But you may find this useful https://github.com/anupy/google-oauth Need to put this library in your project. Or somebody may find useful.