# Laravel socialite 400 Bad Request response

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

**i have created a laravel socialte setup .and it was working before perfectly now its showing error(below).
1)i have changed client_secret
2)created a new oauth credentials
still not working**

```
   public function redirectToGoogle()
        {
            return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
        }



         public function handleGoogleCallback()
        {

                $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();


                $user->getId();        // 1472352
                $user->getNickname();  // "overtrue"
                $name= $user->getName();      // "安正超"
                $emailid= $user->getEmail(); 
                $pic= $user->getAvatar();    // "anzhengchao@gmail.com"
return->redirect('welcome');

}
```

**i have created env file with client_secret and client id**

```
  """
    Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n
    {\n
      "error" : "invalid_grant",\n
      "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed."\n
    }\n
    """
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Google return the **Authentication Code** `code` to your Socialite, it can only be used to exchange to **Access Token** once. Doing more than once will result in the error `Code was already redeemed`.

The flow should be:

1. User click the login button on your website
2. You redirect user to Google and Google is asking user to login/grant you access
3. If successful, Google redirects back to you with a **one-time-use Authentication Code**`?code=.....`
4. Socialite use the `?code` and exchange it with Google to get user's **Access Token**. This can only be done once per flow.
5. You can now request user details using the access token requested in step 4.

Read similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32710034/534862